# 'Syntax error: bad token 'Codeskulptor

Tags: python, syntax, codeskulptor

I'm making a python program to create a graph using codeskulptor and I come up with this error which I have no idea what's wrong with it, how do I solve it?
The code:

```
    pointx = 0
    pointy = 0
    prepointx = 0
    prepointy = 0
    positionx = []
    positiony = []
    def draw_handler(canvas):
        global pointx, pointy 
    for v in range(len(values)):
        if v != 0:
            prepointx = pointx
            prepointy = pointy
        pointx = v * 6 
        pointy = values[v] - 45 * 2
        canvas.draw_point((pointx, pointy), 'red')
        if v != 0: //Syntax error:bad token '' 
            canvas.draw_line((prepointx, prepointy), (pointx, pointy), 3, 'red')  
        frame = simplegui.create_frame('Data', 425, 300)
        frame.set_draw_handler(draw_handler)

        frame.start
```

Comment: This **piece** of code give an other error: "Line 9: NameError: name 'values' is not defined". So I can't find your error.

Comment: This is only part of the code, I defined values earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is wronged indented.
Also `values` is not defined.
But the real problem is probably `frame.start`. To call the start method you must do `frame.start()`.

I made the corrections, see:
http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user40_zJYfuypQ0CWRHRA.py